# Can't use PackageInstaller without PlayStore

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, device-policy-manager, device-owner, packageinstaller

Started testing Android 9 with our Device Owner app where we block Google Play Store and sometimes install APKs (e.g. self update) but, with this setup, the installation fails with `INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK`, `missing codepath`.
With Google Play Store unblocked, installation works.

What changed in SDK28 to cause this? Did Google move the ability to install APKs to Google Play or something? Reading through [Android 9 features and APIs](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0) or [What’s in Android 9 for enterprise apps](https://developer.android.com/work/versions/android-9.0) doesn't reveal anything.

Is it possible to install apks using the PackageInstaller APIs on Android 9 while keeping Google Play Services disabled?

Comment: Having the same issue, but might be device specific. Which device did you test on? I can reproduce this issue on Samsung T395 and G390F with Android 9 (even without DO, but only deactivating PlayStore manually), but not on Pixel 3 with Android 10 and on Emulator with Android 9.